# What is the graph of the polar equation $r = e$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Is it the same as the graph of $y = e$? A straight line?

Comment: No, it is a circle of constant radius $e$ (assuming $e$ is a constant).

Comment: No, since $y=r\sin \theta\neq r$ if $\theta$ varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a circle of radius $e$, centered at the origin.

The rectangular-coordinate equivalent is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = e$, or $x^2 + y^2 = e^2$.